# Add new input boxes on PySimpleGUI when updated

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

I have a dictionary with information :

```
Facets = {
    'Entity'        : {'facet_type': 'Entity'        , 'facet_parameters': ['IFC Class'   , 'Predefined Type']},
    'Attribute'     : {'facet_type': 'Attribute'     , 'facet_parameters': ['Name'        , 'Value']},
    'Classification': {'facet_type': 'Classification', 'facet_parameters': ['System'      , 'Value']},
    'Property'      : {'facet_type': 'Property'      , 'facet_parameters': ['Property Set', 'Name', 'Value']},
    'Material'      : {'facet_type': 'Material'      , 'facet_parameters': ['Value']},
    'Parts'         : {'facet_type': 'Parts'         , 'facet_parameters': ['Entity'      , 'Relationship']}
}
```

I want to create an (IDS) editor using pySimpleGUI. People should select the facet_type and then be able to enter the facet_parameters themself.

so in layout the following allow them to select the correct facet_type :

```
layout = [[sg.Text('All elements of'), 
           sg.Combo(sorted(Facets.keys()),key='-FACET-', enable_events=True)]]
```

And then in the while loop I want that for each parameter in the facet parameters, it gives an imput box but I cant do it

```
window = sg.Window('IDS', layout,resizable=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-FACET-':
        selected_facet = values['-FACET-']
        facet_parameters = Facets[selected_facet]['facet_parameters']
```

So far I am stuck here and can't produce any piece of code that would update the layout to add something like that (screenshot to explain) :

[image: Screenshot showing the desired result]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values for dict `Facets` are fixed, you can build the layout for all elements when initial, just set only which one visible.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def column_layout(category):
    items = Facets[category]['facet_parameters']
    layout = [[sg.Text(item), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key=(category, item))] for item in items]
    return layout

Facets = {
    'Entity'        : {'facet_type': 'Entity'        , 'facet_parameters': ['IFC Class'   , 'Predefined Type']},
    'Attribute'     : {'facet_type': 'Attribute'     , 'facet_parameters': ['Name'        , 'Value']},
    'Classification': {'facet_type': 'Classification', 'facet_parameters': ['System'      , 'Value']},
    'Property'      : {'facet_type': 'Property'      , 'facet_parameters': ['Property Set', 'Name', 'Value']},
    'Material'      : {'facet_type': 'Material'      , 'facet_parameters': ['Value']},
    'Parts'         : {'facet_type': 'Parts'         , 'facet_parameters': ['Entity'      , 'Relationship']}
}

categories = sorted(Facets.keys())
category = categories[0]

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))
sub_column = [[sg.Column(column_layout(category), visible=(i==0), key=category) for i, category in enumerate(categories)]]
layout = [
    [sg.Push(),
     sg.Text('All elements of'),
     sg.Combo(categories, default_value=category, enable_events=True, key='-FACET-'),
     sg.Push()],
    [sg.Column(sub_column)],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-FACET-':
        window[category].update(visible=False)
        category = values[event]
        window[category].update(visible=True)
        window.refresh()
        window.move_to_center()

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was also trying to display a default value of None, and was wondering with this code how would you hide the sub_column then ?

Comment: Also, do you use sorted(Facets.keys()) to get a list list from the dict keys easily ? And if so, are there other methods to do this (let's say without changing the order of display)

Comment: You can add one more Column element with empty layout into `sub_column`, like `category = "None"; sub_column = [[sg.Column([], key="None")] + [sg.Column(column_layout(category), visible=False, key=category) for i, category in enumerate(categories)]]`.

Comment: To get the list from dict keys without changing the order of display, you can do it by `list(Facets.keys()).